# CakePHP label option on input select form not working as expected

Tags: cakephp, forms, label, helper

My select form is working perfectly, but my label will not display no matter the variation or arrangement of arguments.

Here is my code:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('plan_detail_id', $plans_list, array(
    'type' => 'select',
    'label' => 'Select a the Plan Detail',
    'empty' => '-- Select a the Plan Detail --'
)); ?>
```

As you can see I have a second argument `$plan_list` which is normally the place for the label tag. For example, all of my other labels like such are OK:

```
<td><?php echo $this->Form->input('age_id', array(
    'label' => 'Select an Age Range',
    'empty' => '-- Select an Age Range --'
)); ?></td>
```

Note: there is no second `$argument` like the first example. Am I doing something totally wrong? Or is this not possible or a bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The API doesn't show three parameters](http://api.cakephp.org/class/form-helper#method-FormHelperinput) to the `FormHelper::input` method; there is only `$fieldName` and `$options`. You probably meant to use the `FormHelper::select` method instead.

```
$this->Form->select('plan_detail_id', $plans_list, null, array('label' => 'Select a the Plan Detail', 'empty' => '-- Select a the Plan Detail --'));
```

Note that the `FormHelper::select` does not include a wrapping `<div>` or label. To do so you must pass in something like this..

```
echo $this->Form->input(
    'plan_detail_id',
    array(
        'options' => $plans_list,
        'type' => 'select',
        'empty' => '-- Select a the Plan Detail --',
        'label' => 'Select a the Plan Detail'
    )
);
```

This differs from your original attempt in that it moves the `$plans_list` into the array with the `options` argument set.

Comment: Tried that earlier and it does not work, and the pre-entered select item does not show either : (

Comment: Do you mean you get no code to show up? Define "does not work"

Comment: The predefined first select box goes away (from 'empty') and again no label displays above the select box. BUT in my code, the label DOES show in View Source??? Just won't show on the actual UI??

Comment: I fixed the answer. I forgot to include the `$selected` parameter in the query.

Comment: That was my next thought. Thanks. Worked like a charm : )